# How to download pdf files using selenium in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to download pdf files from website using selenium but i am able to open file but its not auto downloadable using code.

Code:

```
chrome_profile = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile = {"download.default_directory": "C:\Users\Downloads",
   "download.prompt_for_download": False,
   "download.directory_upgrade": True,
   "plugins.plugins_disabled": ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]}
chrome_profile.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)
```

Please suggest. Thank you in advance

Comment: which browser are you using ?

Comment: @Prany, google Chrome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing this problem will be solved:

```
prefs = {"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chromedriver = "\path\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your profile section of the code, it is disabling chrome PDF viewer and will trigger auto download

```
"plugins.plugins_disabled": ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]
```