# Downloading a PDF using Selenium, Chrome and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I tried following previous posts on this topic such as these ([post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149534/selenium-webdriver-how-to-download-a-pdf-file-with-python?rq=1), [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677712/how-to-download-pdf-files-using-selenium-in-python)), but I'm still stuck.

My script has to log into a site using a set of credentials, then navigate through some drop down menus to select a report. Once the report is selected, a new window pops up where parameters must be adjusted to generate the report. Once the parameters are set, the same pop up window refreshes with the generated report in PDF format and is displayed using Chrome's built in PDF viewer. I was under the impression that passing certain options to the webdriver would disable this PDF viewer and simply download the file, but the PDF viewer is still being displayed and nothing is automatically downloaded. Surely I'm missing something or I wrote something incorrectly. Here's the jist of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs',  {
    "download.default_directory": download_dir,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.plugins_disabled": ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]
    }
)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

#In between here are a bunch of steps here that navigates through drop down menus

#This step may not be necessary, but I figured I'd include it to address when the pop up window refreshes and displays the report in PDF format through Chrome's PDF viewer
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

So, at this point, Chrome still displays the PDF viewer even though I disabled it earlier. Nothing is downloaded, so I'm wondering if I need to provide another line of code or perhaps something else.

Using Selenium version 3.141.0, Python 3.6.4, Chrome webdriver 2.45 on Windows 10.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but, over in .Net - so I don't have a Python answer for you (thus this comment), but in general you need to pass the following command to Chrome via Selenium: `Page.printToPDF`. My .Net call looked like: `dynamic result = new DDict(chrome.ExecuteChromeCommandWithResult("Page.printToPDF", printToPdfOpts));` then `File.WriteAllBytes(pdfPath, Convert.FromBase64String(result.data));` https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to replace `"plugins.plugins_disabled": ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]`

With:

```
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I tried with the following changes, but it still opens up the PDF in the Chrome PDF viewer: 

   `chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs',  {
        "download.default_directory": download_dir,
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
        }  
    )`

Comment: @sangharsh what version are you using?

Comment: it worked. There was other problem in my code. Found and corrected. Now this solution works. The best one so far! Thanks!! I have already upvoted

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I have used the above lines of code and it still opens the PDF in a new window instead of downloading it. The report is generated through Microstrategy.

Comment: Hi @Omega are you passing the options to the driver instance?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, which I have solved with the firefox driver in Java.
Here is my code:

```
ffprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/pdf");
ffprofile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
ffprofile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
ffprofile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "path/to/directory");
ffprofile.setPreference("plugin.scan.plid.all",false);
ffprofile.setPreference("plugin.scan.Acrobat","99.0");
ffprofile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled",true);
```

Maybe for you it is an option to use Firefox and the Java->Python translation should be simple.

Comment: how to do this java>python transalation?